# How to parallelize the simulations in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Could anybody help me to somehow parallelize this code ? I am about to make some simulations but I STACKED... it takes too long - I even left my computer for 3 days and it did not finished calculating

```
sapply(1:1000, Take_expected_value, points =10^7, number_of_trajectories = 10^7)


Take_expected_value <- function(interval_end = 1, points = 100, number_of_trajectories = 1000){
   return(
      mean(
         exp(
            replicate(
               n = number_of_trajectories,
               expr = Max_from_Wiener_on_interval(interval_end, points)
               )
         )
      )
   ) # This function just replicates max_from_... function, then put values
      # to exp function, and calculates mean of all replications.

}



Max_from_Wiener_on_interval <- function(interval_end = 1, points = 100){

   # time increment
   Delta <- interval_end/points

   # time moments
   time <- seq( 0, interval_end, length = points + 1)

   # Wiener process
   W <-  cumsum( sqrt(Delta) * rnorm( points + 1 ) )
   # return max of "Wiener * sqrt(2) - time moment"
   return(
      max(sqrt(2) * W - time)
      )
}
```

EDIT

After EDIT I am using this code, but it might be a problem of my weak machine(computer). Still it is very slow for me:

```
Take_expected_value <- function(interval_end = 1, points = 100, number_of_trajectories = 1000){
   return(
      mean(
         exp(
            replicate(
               n = number_of_trajectories,
               expr = Max_from_Wiener_on_interval(interval_end, points)
            )
         )
      )
   ) # This function just replicates max_from_... function, then put values
   # to exp function, and calculates mean of all replications.

}


# this function shall not be exported
Max_from_Wiener_on_interval <- function(interval_end = 1, points = 100){

   # time increment
   Delta <- interval_end/points

   # time moments
   time <- seq( 0, interval_end, length = points + 1)

   # Wiener process
   W <-  cumsum( sqrt(Delta) * rnorm( points + 1 ) )
   # return max of "Wiener * sqrt(2) - time moment"
   return(
      max(sqrt(2) * W - time)
   )
}


install.packages("snowfall")
require(snowfall)
cpucores=as.integer(Sys.getenv('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS'))
sfInit( parallel=T, cpus=cpucores) # 
sfExportAll() 
system.time(
   sfLapply(as.list(c(1:1000)),fun=Take_expected_value, points =10^6, number_of_trajectories = 10^6)
)
sfRemoveAll()
sfStop()
```

Comment: I do not see anything particularly bad in the code, but a `sapply` is just a giant loop, and loops runs like molasses in R. Pretty trivial to convert this code to `Julia`, and should be substantially faster.

Comment: Maybe I'll Have a look at Julia someday, but now I'm trying to do everything in R. I was hoping some1 could divide my code that operations would be split to many cores.

Comment: The issue is that what you are asking is too computationally intensive. When I ran the code I used the default values for the other 2 arguments in the function. as soon as I tried running it with a the much larger number of points and trajectories, I waited over 5 minutes for the results and no return. Try running the code you have above but with the default arguments: sfLapply(as.list(c(1:1000)),fun=Take_expected_value) It should take just a few seconds at most (took me 10 secs on 8 cores vs 40 seconds running on serial mode (sfInit( parallel=F))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use snowfall, but there are many other ways to parallelize a function. Here is a generic script with a junk function meant to take a while to compute:

```
Iter_vals=as.list(c(1:16)) # the values to iterate the function with

fx_parallel_run=function(Iter_val, multiplier){ #junk function with 2 arguments 
  jnk=round(runif(1)*multiplier)
  jnk1=runif(jnk)
  for (i in 1:length(jnk1)){
    jnk1[i]=(jnk1[i]*runif(1))+Iter_val[[1]]
  }
  return(jnk1) 
}
require(snowfall)
cpucores=as.integer(Sys.getenv('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS')) #by default snowfall will use the total number of processors, so this is not necessary. 
#However, if you are using the machine for other purposes, 
#you can adapt this line to leave at least a core or two free 
#so the computer is still functional for multi tasking.
sfInit( parallel=T, cpus=cpucores) # 
sfExportAll() 
results=sfLapply(Iter_vals,fun=fx_parallel_run, multiplier=800) #extra function arguments go after the first two sfLapply arguments
sfRemoveAll()
sfStop()
```

in your case, after specifying the functions, I would simply use:

```
require(snowfall)
sfInit( parallel=T, cpus=cpucores) # 
sfExportAll() 
results=sfLapply(as.list(c(1:1000)),fun=Take_expected_value, points =10^7, number_of_trajectories = 10^7)
sfRemoveAll()
sfStop()
```

This may need a little tweaking but I am not going to do all of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping to see that kind of paralleilzaiton :) Hope it'll make operations faster and finishable

Comment: I run this code for smaller sample size and with only 2 iterations but this still does not want finish running and does not want to stop.. I stopped it by myself
  > system.time(
+ results <- sfLapply(1:2, Take_expected_value, points = 10^6, 
+                  number_of_trajectories = 10^6)
+ )

Timing stopped at: 0.06 0 3007.29

Comment: Hi Marcin, sorry I had a minor oversight- since we are using the sfL(ist)apply, we have to provide the values within a list. I have modified the code above to reflect it.

Comment: Oh yeah.. How couldn't i notice this :) Hope it might work well

Comment: I tested on a couple of machines and it worked well. Good luck!

Comment: How much time did it take on your computer to calculate that :) ?

Comment: I have a monster machine: it took 0.2 secs

Comment: It must be. I left it on while night and it did not finish. Could You Please maybe send me the results? bubalodzja@gmail.com :p

Comment: Yeah. That's the whole thing to use bigger arguments :<